# Response and redirect to the page came from

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response.redirect

I have few pages

for ex:

```
          PageA.aspx

          pageB.aspx

          pageC.aspx
```

and I have 1 extra page

ex: AccessChecker.aspx to check whether this user allowed to view this pages in this application

if he allowed he will be redirected to **pageA.aspx**

```
Response.Redirect("~/pageA.aspx");
```

But real question is if someone enter in url such as **www.example.com/pageB.aspx** if its no Session available it will be redirecting that person to  **AccessChecker.aspx** but according to my coding after checking his access level person will be redirected to  **www.example.com/pageA.aspx** But I want that **AccessChecker.aspx** page to redirect to page where that person came from.. in this case user will be redirected to **www.example.com/pageB.aspx** rather **www.example.com/pageA.aspx**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pageB do this

```
if(Session["LoggedIn"]==null)//Check Session
Response.Redirect("AccessChecker.aspx?Nav=B", false);
```

And in your AccessChecker codebehind

```
    //When you want to redirect
    if(Request.QueryString["Nav"]=="B")
    Response.Redirect("~/pageB.aspx", false);
    else
    Response.Redirect("~/pageA.aspx", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

So you could have

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
```

Or something along those lines...

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Navigation framework that will help you, http://navigation.codeplex.com/

First, you configure your pages and the navigation between the pages. Your example would look like:

```
<state key="A" page="~/pageA.aspx">
    <transition key="NoSession" to="Access">
</state>
<state key="B" page="~/pageB.aspx">
    <transition key="NoSession" to="Access">
</state>
<state key="Access" page="~/AccessChecker.aspx"/>
```

Then, to navigate from pageA or pageB to AccessChecker you write:

```
StateController.Navigate("NoSession");
```

And to navigate from AccessChecker back to where they came from you write:

```
StateController.NavigateBack(1);
```